# Gradient vector of scalar field

Tags: vector-analysis, scalar-fields

Calculate the gradient vector of the following scalar field:
$\Phi(r)=\cos(ar)$ where $r$ is the 3-dimensional position (vector) and $a$ is a constant vector.

So gradient means that I need to partially derivative the given function, right? And the components of the gradient are the partial derivatives. A vector can be given like this in 3 dimension: $$v=(ax, by, cz)$$ where $a$, $b$, $c$ are the coefficients, but what is the case with this exercise? Can someone please explain me, how can I solve it?

Comment: If both $\;a,r\;$ are vectors, then what does $\;ar\;$ mean...?

Comment: Do you mean $\cos(a\cdot r)$?

Comment: I guess it is their dot product since _a_ and _r_ both are vectors and they are multiplied by each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\partial_l=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_l}$, $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3);r=(r_1,r_2,r_3)$

$$\nabla(\Phi)=\begin{pmatrix}\partial_1\cos(a_1r_1+a_2r_2+a_3r_3)\\
\partial_2\cos(a_1r_1+a_2r_2+a_3r_3)\\
\partial_3\cos(a_1r_1+a_2r_2+a_3r_3)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-a_1\sin(a\cdot r)\\
-a_2\sin(a\cdot r)\\
-a_3\sin(a\cdot r)\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: thank you so much! now at least I have a picture of what is happening :)